# Overloading addition operator inside a template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to write some code for simple complex number manipulation. I'm using a template class and I'm having trouble overloading operators (specifically +,-,*,/). I'm trying to declare the overload inside my template class, and then define them after in the same header file.

My header code is as follows:

```
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H
#define MY_CLASS_H

template <class T> class complex
{

private:
    T re,im;
public:
    // Constructors & destructor
    complex(){re=im=0;}
    complex(T r, T i){re=r; im=i;}
    ~complex(){}

    // Return real component
    T realcomp() const {return re;}
    // Return imaginary component
    T imagcomp() const {return im;}


    // Overload + operator for addition 
    complex<T> operator+(const complex<T> &C);

....

};
#endif


#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

template <class T> complex<T>& complex<T>::operator+(const complex &C){
complex<T> A(re+C.realcomp(),im+C.imagcomp());
return A;
}
```

This returns errors that I have so far been unable to solve and I'm not entirely sure where I've gone wrong. A mixture of me being a beginner to C++ and trying to puzzle together solutions to other issues on this website has probably meant that my code is a bit of a mess - I apologise!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration for `complex<T>::operator+` is returning a `complex<T>` while the definition is returning a `complex<T>&`. You want to return the object by value, not reference.

Also, template classes must have their function definitions in the header file, since the compiler needs to be able to *see* these when instantiating the templates, so move the `operator+` definition to the header file.

You should also use constructor initialization lists to initialize the member variables.

```
template <class T> class complex
{
private:
    T re,im;
public:
    // Constructors & destructor
    complex() : re(), im() {}
    complex( const T& r, const T& i ) : re(r), im(i) {}
    ~complex(){}

    // Return real component
    T realcomp() const {return re;}
    // Return imaginary component
    T imagcomp() const {return im;}


    // Overload + operator for addition 
    complex<T> operator+(const complex<T> &C)
    {
       return complex<T>( re + C.realcomp(), im + C.imagcomp() );
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for! Out of interest, what advantages are there if I use constructor initialization lists to initialize the member variables?

Comment: @user1331900 The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists) sums it up nicely

Answer (score 0):

You mismatched the declaration with the definition. Change this line:

```
template <class T> complex<T>& complex<T>::operator+(const complex &C){
```

to this

```
template <class T> complex<T> complex<T>::operator+(const complex &C){
```

(Note the missing "&")

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
template <class T> complex<T> complex<T>::operator+(const complex<T> &C){ 
  complex<T> A(re+C.realcomp(),im+C.imagcomp()); 
  return A; 
}
```

The return value is declared to be an object in the class and the patameter is missing the template parameter

Answer (score 0):

you are returning a local variable as reference. plus the declaration are different:

you declare to return a complex while on definition you return a complex&