# Giving default values to reference member variables

Tags: c++, class, reference, constructor, object-lifetime

so I've made a class in c++ which has 2 reference type members:

```
class Edge{
private:
const Node& base;
const Node& target;

public:
    Edge(const Node& new1, const Node& new2);
```

I want to give default values to base and target in the C'tor. Which means that:

```
Edge()
```

will not be an error, but will do create an Edge object. How do I do that?

edit:
I'm also trying to do:

```
Edge::Edge(const Node& newBase, const Node& newTarg)
{
    m_base=newBase;
    m_target=newTarg;
}
```

But it won't let me, it says no operator "=" matches this operators. But I did make a "=" operator for Nodes and checked it worked.......

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to write default arguments for functions?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Adding default arguments doesn't really help.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  What are you trying to do with reference member variables?

Comment: @BenVoigt - looks like it was the initaliser lists causing the issue, not the lifetime of the temporaries :)

Comment: @awoodland: He just hadn't gotten that far yet ;)

Comment: You cannot assign references, and hence you cannot assign objects which *contain* references. It just doesn't make sense. Perhaps you want something like a `std::reference_wrapper`, which gives you a value-wrapper around a reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give `new1` and `new2` defaults like any other parameter. The trick is that since they're passed by reference and (presumably) you're using them to set `base` and `target` they need to live long enough for this to make sense. You can do that by making a static "dummy" `Node` to use as the default for where one hasn't been specified, e.g.:

```
class Node {};

class Edge{
private:
static const Node none;
const Node& base;
const Node& target;

public:
    Edge(const Node& new1=none, const Node& new2=none) : base(new1), target(new2) {}
};

const Node Edge::none;

int main() {
  Edge e;
}
```

If that's good design or not is another issue though. There might well be a smarter solution to the underlying problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: i edited my question and added one thing: now my normal c'tor with values doesnt work too.

Comment: @Jjang - that's a slightly different issue, there's a good answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4589276/168175 - basically you need to use the initaliser list syntax like I did in my answer regardless of if you have a default or not.

Comment: i got the point but i dont know what to do in my case. should i make 2 false nodes, just to initialize the const?

Comment: @Jjang in the case you just added to your question you can do: `Edge::Edge(const Node& newBase, const Node& newTarg) : base(newBase), target(newTarget) {}`

Comment: sure? my Node objects are getting int and not Node type. is that still good?

Comment: p.s another error. "provides no intialization for:"
i was trying to make a c'ctor.. >_>

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that works for non-constant references, too:

```
struct Bar { /* ... */ }:

struct Foo
{
    Foo(Bar & br) : b(br)          { }
    Foo()         : b(default_bar) { }
private:
    static Bar default_bar;
    Bar & b;
};
Bar Foo::default_bar;
```

This way, all default-constructed `Foo` instances contain a reference to the common, static `default_bar` object.

Comment: edited question, now even my normal c'tor with values doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a wrapper that is copyable

```
struct Reference
    {
    T* r_noncopyable_object;
    };
```