# Xcode 4.6 crash because of ARC?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c++

Unbelievable in Xcode 4.6.

If I initialize a variable to something, it frees the memory. But what if this variable has a random value ?

```
class X 
{

private:

    NSThread* thr;

public:

    X();
}; 
X :: X()
    {
        thr = 0; // BOOM !!!?
    }
X* x = new X(); // Constructor crashes.
```

But if the constructor is inline, it doesn't!

Comment: How is it related to Xcode? Do you really think that it wouldn't do the same if you used another IDE?

Comment: In Xcode 4.5 it worked as expected. 
If it crashes in Xcode 4.6, how am I supposed to initialize the variables then?

Comment: @ericgorr They aren't. In C and C++, the constant numeric value `0`, when assigned or compared to a pointer, is implicitly treated as `NULL`.

Comment: It crashes when, for some reason, the "thr" isn't initialized to 0. I supposed that this was the default with ARC ?

Comment: I edited it. It crashes when the object is created with new.
It crashes because, on new, the x->thr has a random value. Setting it to 0 causes ARC to try to release the old pointer, which is not valid.

Comment: Still doesn't crash for me. Provide more information.

Comment: Well I don't know what to try. In another project, the variables in the class are automatically initialized to 0, so it works. In this project, the variables in the class get random values and then it crashes on the constructor.

Comment: UPDATE: It doesn't crash when the constructor is inlined. Try the edited sample. When the constructor is not inline, it crashes.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to [initialize the member variable](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr387.htm) like this in a C++ constructor? `X :: X() : thr(0) { }`

Comment: Your example will crash when thr is pointing to random memory on construction. This is not always the case. I solved it by inlining the constructor or to initialize it by thr(0).

Comment: Inlining the constructor may happen to work for you today, but I wouldn't depend on it.

Comment: Please let the question as a question and do not put the solution in the question once it's resolved. Also avoid putting solved in the title. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a C++ constructor, you need to use an [initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists) to set the initial value of the member variable.

```
X :: X() : thr(nil) 
{
}
```

Otherwise, like you are seeing, `thr` will initially have a garbage value, and you might crash when ARC tries to send `-release` to that value.

As the [ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) says:

> ARC cannot differentiate between an assignment operator which is intended to “initialize” dynamic memory and one which is intended to potentially replace a value.