# Initializer list vs. initialization method

Tags: c++

There are at least two ways to initialize a class in C++.

(1) Initializer List

```
struct C
{
  int i;
  C() : i(0) {}
};
```

(2) Initializer Method

```
struct D
{
  int i;
  C() { init(); }
  void init() {
    i = 0;
  }
};
```

I need to re-init objects of my class from time to time. With the second solution, I can simply call `obj.init()`. With the first solution, I would either have to add an `init()` function which essentially duplicates the initializer list effect or use `obj = C()`.

Is there a more-or-less consensus on what variant is better here? Is there a disadvantage to using an initializer method (except the possible loss of performance as [mentioned in the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html)).

Comment: For POD members there's probably no performance penalty.

Comment: Well, you cannot always default initialize types, in which case variant (2) would not be an option.

Comment: As long as you don't hit one of the cases where the compiler does not allow this and you keep the performance concerns in mind then `init` is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating an array (using vector, or allocating dynamically using `new`) you will have to explicitly call `init` on each of its members while using a constructor, it will automatically be called for all elements.

I prefer placing basic initialization into the constructor and more complex logic into an init method. In my opinion a constructor should not perform any complex operations.

Answer (score 6):

The main difference is that without using initialization list, members are created and then values are assigned to them. When you use initialization list, members are directly created by using given values.

One of situations, when using initialization is important, is when your class holds some references as a members and it is necessary to initialize these members right when they are being constructed:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(B& bRef) : bRef_(bRef) { }
private:
    B& bRef_;   
}
```

This question could help you too: [In this specific case, is there a difference between using a member initializer list and assigning values in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists)

Your `init()` method is perfectly fine. As you yourself have mentioned, you want to initialize these members more times than just first time when the instance of this class is being constructed, so for the sake of reusability and simplicity it's right to keep it in a method. **Don't try to improve performance of your code unless you really need it.**

Some people say that **It's easier to make a correct program fast than it's to make a fast program correct.** ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below are the scenarios when initializer list is used:

- For initialization of non-static const data members.
- For initialization of reference members.
- For initialization of member objects which do not have default constructor.
- For initialization of base class members.
- When constructor’s parameter name is same as data member.
- For Performance reasons.