# Smart unique pointer as a member variable

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a class as:

```
class LargeObject
{
  public:
    LargeObject();
    void DoSomething();
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<Thing> pThing;
};
```

Then when I want to create the pointer in the constructor

```
LargeObject()
{
  pThing(new Thing()); //This does not work.
}
```

I want to use the member variable throughout the code.  How to do that?

Comment: How would you initialize `pThing` if it was, say, an `int`? Try that first. When you succeed, try the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Although the linked duplicate question concerns `shared_ptr`s, `unique_ptr` can be initialized from a pointer to `Thing` the same way using constructor initialization lists. Other member variables can also be initialized in initialization lists, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689227/initializer-list-vs-initialization-method) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242830/constructor-initialization-list-evaluation-order).

Comment: OK, that seems the way to go. I will try it out.  Tnx

Answer (score 1):

I think initialization should be in constructor's initialization list, that's the place where constructors should be invoked from another constructor:

```
LargeObject()
:pThing(new Thing){}
```

Comment: It can be, here and elsewhere it says use "new"  http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/C++11_smart_ptrs.pdf like a regular pointer.