# Weird polymorphism c++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Anyone can explain this weird bit in this line of code to me?

ClassA::ClassA(std::string aName) ***: name(aName)***

Appearantly, this is the declaration of that class

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    std::string name;
    ClassA(std::string aName);
};
```

And the weird line of code appeared in its cpp file

```
ClassA::ClassA(std::string aName) : name(aName)
```

It's not polymorphism right? But then, what is it?

Comment: That's a member initializer list, nothing to do with polymorphism. It initializes the member `name` with the value `aName`.

Comment: @user, perhaps you could pick up a "learn C++ in 24 hours" book and read chapter 1. Or better, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a constructor with an initialization list:

```
 ClassA::ClassA(std::string aName) 
 : name(aName) // constructor initialization list
 {
   // ctor body. name is already initialized here
 }
```

It means data member `name` gets initialized with the value of `aName`.

It is orthogonal to polymorphism.

Comment: so I could assume that it's equivalent to declaring 'name' as a data member in the class declaration right. but if that's the case, then what is the scope of that data member? private?

Comment: @user2345939 it is not equivalent. `name` has to be a data member (or a base class). You are initializing `name`. `private`, `public` or `protected` doesn't matter here, it could be either.

Comment: no, this doesn't declare the member, it just initializes it. It still has to be declared in the class definition.

Answer (score 3):

it's a member initializer. Member

```
std::string name;
```

will be initilized with `aName`
Using this allows to skip the default constructor of std::string, which would be used otherwise, so this removes some overhead. Another option would be

```
ClassA::ClassA(std::string aName)
{
  // name is fist constucted with default constructor
  name = aName;  // value is assigned with operator =
}
```

and this is generally slower, and should be avoided

Comment: you are right. i just did a quick research on member initializer and found out that initializing data member inside the class is actually less  efficient

Answer (score 0):

It's just the initialisation list. When you specify the constructor you can initialise member variables in this list.

Answer (score 0):

Its an [initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists), which is a neat and clear way of initializing member variables in C++