# c++ class members and delayed initialization

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11

I am currently looking into new `c++11` `random` library. For simplification, I created following class

```
class my_rand {
    private:
        std::mt19937_64 eng;
    public:
        my_rand() {
            std::array<int, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data;
            std::random_device rd;
            std::generate_n(seed_data.data(), seed_data.size(), std::ref(rd));
            std::seed_seq seq(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data));
            this->eng.seed(seq);
        };
        unsigned long long operator() () {
            return this->eng();
        };
};
```

so that I can just do `my_rand rand;` once and then repeatedly call `rand()` to generate random numbers.

However, now I want to use `std::uniform_int_distribution` to set bound to numbers I get. It seams obvious to specify bounds while creating the object, so that invocations stay the same. The problem is, if I add private member (something like `std::uniform_int_distribution<long long> uid;`) then later in constructor I will not be able to set bounds because `uid` will already be initialized. I could not find method of `std::uniform_int_distribution` which allowed to set limits after it is created.

I may well be missing some point here, so thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use an initializer list.

Comment: Maybe it still can be done in the old-school constructor parameter way? And thanks anyway, it is a way to go I guess.

Comment: @jogojapan Now that you pointed out I see that it probably is =(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [initializer lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists) to construct member variables or base classes. (See [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html) for more info)

```
my_rand(...arguments...) : uid(...arguments...) //<-- Initializer list
{
    //...stuff...
} //<-- No semicolon after function definition.
```

If that doesn't suit your needs, you can always go like this:

```
myVar = int(27);
```

For example:

```
//Initial construction:
std::uniform_int_distribution<> testA(1, 6);

//Re-assignment by copy-construction (move-construction actually)
//and a temporary object.
testA = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(5, 10);
```

Comment: Yeah  about that, extra semicolons are not restricted yet it seams more consistent with class declarations. I know that class declaration can be followed by objects declarations and function cannot, but still...

Comment: That won't work for you when using lambdas - the extra semicolons will cause compile errors there. =)

Comment: Oh, thanks for warning. Did not look into that area yet.