# assigning constant value to struct members to be used in 1 class

Tags: c++, class, struct, constants, program-entry-point

So far I've read about structs, with and without pointers. My question is about a struct in combination with a class and main. What I learn from K&R and c++ sites is that a struct can't contain values. The values I want to assign to the members will be constants. In several posts I read that I should put the struct inside the class and even inside private. The setup I use was:

```
class C
{
struct something {const float m = 3} s;` //actually 12 members. Compiler doesn't accept  values: "ISO C++ forbids initialization of member"

function foo(struct something s){ float m = s.m; <..do something..>}` //struct s actually used in several functions

};    

int main(){C c;}
```

Then I created 2 structs, and letting the 2nd assign values to the members of the first, which I find ugly. But why did that get accepted by gcc? So how can I assign the values only once in a proper way since assigning values has to be done inside a function. BTW, I'm using Ubuntu gcc-4.6.1.

Thank you for an answer.

Comment: You are confusing languages. In C++, `class` and `struct` are essentially the same. You can express exactly the same types using either.

Comment: structs can't contain values?

Comment: Of course structs can contain values. And you shouldn't use K&R to learn C++, since it's about a different language. You might find a [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) more useful.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ is that `struct`s default their members to `public` while classes default to `private` (same goes for inheritance). That's all there is to it.

Then, in C++03 `const float m = 3;` is not valid as a member declaration. You would need to declare a constructor for your struct:

```
struct something
{
    const float m;
    const float n;
    something() : m(3), n(42) {}
} s;
```

Comment: How do you do this when there are more constants? Now I get "something() cannot be overloaded".

Comment: @user2294285 updated my snippet for two constants, more are analogue

Comment: Thank you. I've searched for this in Stroustrup 3rd ed., but as far as I can see the examples don't show this. Where can I find more of this ?

Comment: @user2294285 That concept is called an [initialization list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists) (not to be confused with the C++11 feature `std::initializer_list`) and you should be able to find something on that; but I don't have access to the book so I can't say for sure

Answer (score 1):

```
struct something {const float m = 3} s;` //actually 12 members. Compiler doesn't accept  values: "ISO C++ forbids initialization of member"
```

to fix above do

```
struct something {
    something (float const& f = 3) : m(f)
    const float m;
} s;
```

Comment: Why the const reference?

Comment: The first line is valid C++, unless you are using C++03.

Comment: Why the const ref? Because the default value 3 (which is literal) only have const ref.

Comment: Don't use const references for PODs. The dereferencing may be more expensive than the copy. Compilers may optimize that, but I wouldn't rely on it. You may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Structs AND classes in C++ suffer from this problem. You can only declare a value in a class definition if the variable is static and shared among all the instances of the class. If your variable is const I think that may be a good choice.

A good solution for non-const variables is a simple one - assign the desired values to all the variables in the default constructor of your class or struct.

e.g

```
struct Something
{
  float value;

  Something():value(5.0f) {};

}
```

Comment: That doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: @juanchopanza What doesn`t apply anymore? I made two points please be specific as to which point you are referring, and also please state which standard changed the rules.

Comment: Your first point. You can now say `struct Foo { int i = 42; };`. `i` doesn't have to be `const static`.

Comment: That`s great to know! Thank you. Is this something that came with c++11 or did an earlier standard change that? Have I been sleeping for years?

Comment: It is new in C++11. You've only been sleeping for two years :-) To be fair, this feature took a while to implement in the most popular compilers.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I really should learn some C++ 11 things, haven`t had the chance yet. However, the thought of C++ with even MORE features makes it that much more intimidating.