# Derive Smiley from Circle

Tags: c++

I am trying to derive class Smiley from Circle:

```
struct Smiley : Circle {
  void draw_lines() const;
};

void Smiley::draw_lines() const {
  Circle::draw_lines();   // outline
  /*rest of code here*/
}
```

This is the definition of Circle:

```
struct Circle : Shape {
  Circle(Point p, int rr);    // center and radius

  void draw_lines() const;

  Point center() const;

  void set_radius(int rr) { set_point(0, Point(center().x - rr, center().y - rr)); r = rr; }
  int radius() const { return r; }
private:
  int r;
};
```

I basically want a Circle with a couple arcs drawn on top.  Theoretically, I should only have to write `draw_lines()` over (which is defined as `virtual` in Shape), but it does nothing without a constructor, and if I have a constructor, it get an error and says that Circle does not have a default constructor available, even if I have no code in the constructor relating to Circle.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Comment: the error the compiler gives is self explanatory...

Comment: But Circle does have a constructor, so why am I getting this error?  I would just derive Smiley directly from Shape and redo the implementation details, but the assignment (not for class, just learning on my own) says to derive it from Circle.

Comment: @user2509848: It has a constructor, yes, and that constructor requires arguments. You're not giving it any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When you inherit from a class with no default constructor, you have to make sure you invoke the non-default one.**

Otherwise your derived class *tries* to invoke that non-existent default constructor, as the error says. In this case, you can probably just pass the same arguments straight through.

```
struct Smiley : Circle {
  Smiley(Point p, int rr);
  void draw_lines() const;
};

Smiley::Smiley(Point p, int rr)
   : Circle(p, rr)
{};
```

---

> I basically want a Circle with a couple arcs drawn on top

Then it's not a circle any more, so why does `Smiley` inherit `Circle`?

Comment: Because the outline of the face is a Circle.  As I said in a comment above, this is an assignment.

Comment: @user2509848: So the smiley _contains_ a circle, but it's not true that it _is_ a circle. I'd suggest composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: I do not know composition yet.  The assignment is to inherit Circle (I am learning inheritance), but I will look into this.

Comment: @user2509848: Yeah, fine, I'm just making sure you understand that. To my mind it's probably one of the most important lessons to learn from this assignment. :)

Comment: @user2509848: You are welcome. Did you understand _how_ it works?

Comment: Yes, Smiley's constructor calls Circle's constructor with the arguments to create it.  I knew this needed to happen, but I didn't know how to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a constructor for circle that requires a Point and a Radius. You should define one with identical parameters for `Smiley`, that invokes the base class constructor with those parameters, via a [Member Initialiser List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists).

```
struct Smiley : Circle {
  Smiley(Point p, int rr) : Circle(p, rr)
  {
  } 
  void draw_lines() const;
};
```

Comment: This can be better worded, esp. considering you're trying to explain to a novice. "You need to define an identical one for Smiley" is just plain wrong.

Comment: So I just need to define a blank constructor for these problems?

Comment: @user2509848 - the constructor isn't 'blank'. While it has an empty code body, the important thing is that is initializes the *base class* via an initialization list.

Comment: Let us call it the _member initialiser list_; "initialization list" is now an overloaded term.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Agreed. Extra verbiage is always a good idea. (sighs deeply...)

Comment: I see.  Smiley's constructor invokes Circle's constructor with the arguments.

Comment: @Roddy: Teehee ;) To be fair, the standard uses this terminology too, along with `mem-initializer-list` and `ctor-initializer` in the grammar.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore better now? ;-)