# What does explicitly initializing a member mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

In the following code

```
class someClassB;

class someClassA
{
public:
    someClassA(int x, int y);
private:
    someClassB* B;
};

class someClassB
{
public:
    someClassB(int x, int y);
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    someClassA A;
};

someClassA::someClassA(int i, int j) 
{
    B->x = i;
    B->y = j;
}

someClassB::someClassB(int i, int j)
{
    x = i;
    y = j;
    A = new someClassA(i, j);
}
```

why do I get an error saying 'Constructor for 'someClassB' must explicitly initialize the member 'A' which does not have a default constructor'?
Am I not initializing 'A' in someClassB's constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`someClassA` does not have a default constructor. Currently, `someClassB` needs to default initialize it, resulting in the compilation error you quote. .You need to explicitly *initialize* the `someClassA` data member using one of its available constructors. For example,

```
someClassB::someClassB(int i, int j) : x(i), y(j), A(i, j)
{
}
```

Here, `x` and `y` are also *initialized* in the constructor initialization list, as opposed to default initialized and then assigned values to, as in your code.

Also note that, in general, this makes no sense in C++:

```
A = new someClassA(i, j);
```

`new` returns a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you are using `A` with `new`, I suspect you meant to declare it as a pointer:

```
someClassA* A;
```

If not, then you need to initialize it in `someClassB`'s [initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4589276/367273).

Answer (score 0):

```
someClassA::someClassA(int i, int j) 
{
    B->x = i;
    B->y = j;
}
```

create a new instance of class someClassB as `B` is a pointer and you didn't allocated memory for this.

```
A = new someClassA(i, j);
```

A is not a pointer this is an instance of `someClassA`