# What does a : do after a function declaration?

Tags: c++

```
Rectangle(Point2D center, double w, double h, double r, double g, double b):center(center)
    {
        ...
    }
```

What does the `:center(center)` part of this code do?

Comment: Initialization list. Google it.

Comment: It sets a variable owned by the class to the value encapsulated inside the parenthesis.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists)

Comment: Note that this syntax is only allowed in constructors, not function declarations in general.

Comment: Why not read the C++ book?

Answer (score 1):

`:` initializes `center` member with `center` parameter.

In most case (not always!) your code

```
Rectangle(Point2D center, double w, double h, double r, double g, double b):center(center)
{
    ....
}
```

could be replaced with

```
Rectangle(Point2D center, double w, double h, double r, double g, double b)
{
    this->center = center;
    ....
}
```

You can read more about initialization lists in C++ [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Comment: Why not just have center as a function parameter?

Comment: You should explain the difference between the two.

Comment: I have added a link about initialization lists to make my answer complete.

Answer (score 0):

It's used to initialize the element . Since C++ is object oriented everything is treated as object even datatypes. so when you use initialization list the object are initialized when the object is created for it.

This is considered to better(faster) way then assigning to the variable directly.

As definition and declaration happens in one go.