# Initilize constructor of class from another class

Tags: c++

I have class A with constructor A(int a)

**A.h**

```
calss A{
  public :  A(int a);
}
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>
A::A(int a)
{
    std::cout<<a<<end;
}
```

I need to initialize this class from another class B,

I tried

**B.h**

```
class B{
   public :  B();
            A tmp;
            //A tmp(4); //this  giving syntax error          
}
```

and

**B.cpp**

```
 B(){
     tmp = A(4);
}
```

But I am getting compiler error "`error: no matching function for call to 'A::A()'`"

Comment: (1) Post the complete error message.  (2) Constructors don't have return types, so remove the `void`.

Comment: Constructors can not have return type. Not even void.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In this specific case, is there a difference between using a member initializer list and assigning values in a constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/in-this-specific-case-is-there-a-difference-between-using-a-member-initializer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `A` doesn't have a default constructor (because if you define another constructor and default one is not generated) and so `A` objects cannot be default constructed.

The solution is to use constructor initialization lists for **every** constructor of `B` where you call the appropriate constructor for `tmp`.

```
class B {
   A tmp;

public:
   B() : tmp(4) {}
};
```

If you can use c++11 and in every (or at least most of the) constructors of `B` you create `tmp` the same way you can use:

```
class B {
  A tmp{4};

public:
  B() {};
}
```

Comment: tmp is not local variable, I need to use this as class member.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors should not have a return type. Remove the void in the declaration and you should be good to go. Same goes for your class B.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are special member functions without any return type.

```
//A tmp(4); //this  giving syntax error
```

This will for sure give you an error because you mentioned

```
 void A(int a)
```

and this is not constructor; because its has return type (void).
when you explicitly define parametrized constructor (like A(int a) )the default constructor gets vanished and for this statement

```
A tmp;
```

to compile you have to provide your own default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great always to post complete error message.

Rather than getting "no matching function for call to" , I am sure that you will be getting below error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
note:                 A::A(int)
```

This clearly indicates that default constructor A::A() is missing from your code as you have provided your own constructor.

**Suggestion**: You have defined conversion constructor. It is good practice to use "**explicit**" keyword.

Comment: hi. this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @bolov : Yes you are right. But my answer actually contains answer and suggestion both.

Answer (score 1):

*.h file

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(int a);
};
class B
{
    public:
        B();
        A *tmpA;
};
```

*.cpp file

```
A::A(int a)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,L"",L"", MB_OK);
}
B::B()
{
    tmpA = new A(4);
}
```

usage

```
{
    B *b = new B();
}
```

is it correct for you?